# How do you turn one color into another color?

Tags: css, styles

rgba(255, 0, 0, 1); // red

rgba(0, 255, 0, 1); // just turned red green

How would you turn rgba(154, 155, 235); (a light purply blue color) into the same color only orange?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? "into the same color only orange" doesn't seem to make a lot of sense!

Comment: Programmatically? CSS cannot do that. Also you don't explain your conversion rule from color A to color B.

Comment: You might find this helpful: [The Code Side Of Color](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/04/the-code-side-of-color/)

Comment: You know, I think I just found the answer. Hue. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite confusing (also fyi, you're also misusing `rgba` in your last example, but you used it properly elsewhere so that was probably just an oversight) but I'm assuming that you want to maintain the lightness and saturation of the colour and modify the hue. To do this use `hsl` instead

```
hsl(239, 67%, 76%)
```

is equivalant to

```
rgb(154, 155, 235)
```

So by using `hsl` you can now change the hue

```
hsl(239, 67%, 76%)

hsl(14, 67%, 76%)

hsl(167, 67%, 76%)

hsl(0, 67%, 76%)
```

You can use `hsl` anywhere you'd use a normal hex color or `rgba` color.

See http://jsfiddle.net/a7pGB/ for an example

Comment: @user1526247 No problem, happy to help. Don't forget to accept if you're happy with the answer!